# Proof Critique: For any $b\in \mathbf{N}$, $b++$ is unique.

Tags: proof-explanation

As I was trying to answer this question (using only the peano axioms), I came up with the following "proof". On a second look, I noticed a flaw. But I'm struggling to articulate why or what the flaw is. Could somebody take a look, and let me know if I'm on the right track? Thanks!

$\textbf{Incorrect Proof}$: Take any arbitrary $b \in \mathbf{N}$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some $a,a' \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $b++=a$ and $b++ = a'$. Then we can write $a = b++ = a'$ yielding $a=a'$ as required.

$\textbf{Self-critique}$: I am assuming that $b++$ doesn't have two different successors. What if we're working with some number system where it does? The right way to show this is induction on $b$ that uses the axiom "if $n\neq m$, then $n++ \neq m++$."

Comment: You ought to learn logic first...

Comment: How is $b\text{++}$ defined in your context? If this is the successor function in Peano Axioms, then it is *assumed* to have a unique value for each $b\in \mathbf{N}$.

Comment: We have the following definitions: 1) $n \in \mathbb{N} \to n++ \in \mathbb{N}$, 2) for all $n$, $n++ \neq 0$, and 3) $\forall n.(n\neq m \to n++\neq m++)$.

Comment: @skm Sure. But usually, right before you get to that part, the successor function is defined as a _function_. And part of the definition of a function is exactly that for any input the output is unique. Is this the case for you? And if not, then what _is_ your $++$?

Comment: @Arthur I don't see a successor function in the definition for incrementation. What I do have is a proposition that follows from the axiom stating induction about recursive definitions: Suppose for each $n \in N$, we have some function $f_n :N\to N$. Take some $c \in N$. Then we can assign a unique natural number $a_n$ to each natural number $n$, such that $a_0 := c$ and $a_n++ := f_n(a_n)$. Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: Alternatively, we have an informal definition stating $0++ = 1, 1++ = 2, etc.$

Comment: We can come up with a model, different from $\mathbf{N}$, that satisfies all the Peano axioms except the 'uniqueness of successor' part. For instance, prepare two copies of $\mathbf{N}$ and identify their initial elements.

Comment: I'll repeat myself that you need to learn logic first, because if you knew basic logic you would not even consider your 'incorrect proof' because it makes completely no logical sense... Trying to use Peano Arithmetic without basic logic is like trying to jump off a cliff without something to hold you up.

Comment: And mathematics does not use "$++$". It's ugly and incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment user21820. For the basic logic piece, I have learned logic. I'm using these first chapters as a way to firm up those concepts, and hence, the struggles. As for the "++", I'm using the same notation used in the book I'm going through (Analysis by Terence Tao). I think I've got a good sense from the above comments what I need to do, so I'll write it up and post here relatively soon. All the help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You write

> Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is some $a,a' \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $b++=a$ and $b++ = a'$. Then we can write $a = b++ = a'$ yielding $a=a'$ as required.

We cannot conclude this, as we are assuming that $b\!+\!\!+$ is not unique.